# First page of new section does not include page number

Tags: microsoft-word, format, layout, page-numbers, linebreaks

First page of new section does not include page number (the new section has two-column layout format). Any idea why and how to solve this?

I could hardcode the page number, but I am afraid of messing something up (I have automatically generated table of contents & bibliography. The problematic page can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3xcT.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqJsL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry! It was trivial; solved it by going to page layout then page setup as described in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNVyx.png) taken from [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/174505/how-to-omit-the-page-number-from-the-first-page-of-a-word-2013-document-without-using-sections/)